# How to set return value when javascript called from code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a link button as below

```
<atoms:StoreLink Visible="<%# !ECommUtilities.HideTopSubmitOrderButtonCountries  %>"   OnServerClick="Continue_Clicked" Caption="<%# CheckoutCaption %>" localefile="ECOMM_CAPTION" runat="server" ID="_continue" AuthEnabled="false" OnClientClick="<%# GetVerifyIovationMethodNam %>" />
```

my Javascript function is

```
function preventDuobleClickEvent(element) {
            alert('Prevent');
            if (!isSubmit) {
                isSubmit = true;
                element.disabled = true;
                return true;
            }
            else {
                alert('elseCond');
                return false;
            }
        }
```

now how can i make so that my Linkbutton client click is expecting a return

I tried this It did not work

```
 <atoms:StoreLink Visible="<%# !ECommUtilities.HideTopSubmitOrderButtonCountries  %>"   OnServerClick="Continue_Clicked" Caption="<%# CheckoutCaption %>" localefile="ECOMM_CAPTION" runat="server" ID="_continue" AuthEnabled="false" OnClientClick="return<%# GetVerifyIovationMethodNam %>" />
```

Comment: What is ***atoms:StoreLink*** sever control? Without knowing which control it inherited from, we could not say whether it has ***OnClientClick*** event.

Answer (score 0):

The easies way is to set the `OnClientClick` value from code behind since it looks like you want to use a variable as a return value for javascript. Here is an example.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

And then in code behind:

```
Button1.OnClientClick = "return preventDuobleClickEvent('" + GetVerifyIovationMethodNam + "')";
```